# How do I search a user within location using graph api?

Tags: facebook, fb-graph

I am new to this. I am looking for a way to search user in specific location but it turn out the results come from no where.

I have tried this

/search?q=micheal&type=user&location=New+York

But the results shows people from like India. I wonder why it becomes like that. Each time I refreshing the link it shows the same set of data.

I am using php sdk with app version 2.8.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to search for users by location, you can only search for users by name. That is why people from India show up too. Check out the docs, there is no mention of using the location parameter with the user search, especially not with a location name. Location search is only possible for Places, with latitude/longitude.